# While adding armv7 to the project ->buildsettings -> Excluded Architecture, arm64 added automatically to Target ->buildsettings> Excluded Architecture

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I'm using the google_ml_kit_object_detection package when i add armv7 into the project ->buildsettings -> Excluded Architecture....
[image: Image One]
arm64 added automatically to Target ->buildsettings> Excluded Architecture-> Any Emulator SDK...
[image: Image Two]
when i try to remove it it throw me error "Target Integrity (Xcode): The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64". while when i added arm64 the app run normally but i can't use any ios emulator(arm64)..

How to solve this issue

Comment: Please see my comment on your other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510286/once-i-removed-arm64-from-the-target-excluded-architecture-any-ios-simluta