# Once i removed arm64 from the "Target-> Excluded Architecture -> Any IOS Simlutaor" an error occur " framework not found FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: xcode, flutter, google-mlkit

I'm using google-mlkit-object-detection package, which when i run the app in the emulator arm64 added automatically into the "Target-> Excluded Architecture -> Any IOS Simlutaor" and when i tried to remove it an error occur " framework not found FirebaseAnalytics' only in the IOS simulator while in any other devices it works perfect.

Comment: I assume that you are running on a M1 Mac (you can verify by checking the top left Apple icon -> About This Mac to see if you have "Chip: Apple M1" in the pop-up window). If so, ML Kit does not support the arm64 simulator on M1 yet. You can only test your app using a real device connected to your M1 mac.